# How to split a string without spaces into an array of words?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm practicing javascript at freecodecamp.org by making an algorithm of a telephone checker. I succeeded in checking it when only the provided phone number is a string of numbers. Now I'm stuck and don't know how to check it if the provided phone number contain words such as 'sixnineone'. So I want to split it into "six nine one" or convert them into "691" with an array of number objects.

**Here's the problem:**

(https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/telephone-number-validator)

I tried to get some hints via the website, but they only solve the problem with regular expressions which i don't understand well.

here is what I've done:

```
    function telephoneCheck(str) {
    let phoneNum = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^1-9a-z]/g, "");
    let numbers = [
        {0: "o"},
        {1: "one"},
        {2: "two"},
        {3: "tree"},
        {4: "four"},
        {5: "five"},
        {6: "six"},
        {7: "seven"},
        {8: "eight"},
        {9: "nine"}
    ];

    if (phoneNum.match(/[1-9]/)) {
        phoneNum = phoneNum.split('')

        if (phoneNum.length === 10) {
            phoneNum.unshift(1);
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < phoneNum.length; i++) {
            phoneNum[i] = Number(phoneNum[i]);
        }

        if (phoneNum.length === 11 && phoneNum[0] === 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    if (phoneNum.match(/[a-z]/)) {
        console.log(phoneNum);
    }
}

console.log(telephoneCheck("sixone"));
```

In the solution of the problem, it is said that the only solution is their's, but if what I think is right then there might be another one.

Comment: Of course there are usually multiple ways to go about a problem like this. Is there an actual question here, or …?

Comment: My problem is that i don't know how to split an array if it contains numbers in words and digits like: "one7eightsix9tree". I want to split it in order to convert the "one", "eight","six", "tree" thanks to an object the numbers array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and use the names as a key and the value as the number.

Then extract the keys from the map, order them so that the longest string comes first and create a regex with a capturing group and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

The regex would eventually look like:

```
(three|seven|eight|four|five|nine|one|two|six|o)
```

Then split the string using this regex. Map over the items removing all non digits when the map does not contain the key and remove all empty values from the array.

Finally get the value from the map by using the key.

```js
let map = new Map([
  ["o", 0],
  ["one", 1],
  ["two", 2],
  ["three", 3],
  ["four", 4],
  ["five", 5],
  ["six", 6],
  ["seven", 7],
  ["eight", 8],
  ["nine", 9]
]);
let regex = new RegExp("(" + [...map.keys()]
  .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
  .join('|') + ")");

let strings = [
  "69ooooneotwonine",
  "o",
  "testninetest",
  "10001",
  "7xxxxxxx6fivetimesfifefofourt",
  "test"

].map(s =>
  s.split(regex)
  .map(x => !map.has(x) ? x.replace(/\D+/, '') : x)
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(x => map.has(x) ? map.get(x) : x)
  .join(''));

console.log(strings);
```